# Removing var_dump from PHP code

Tags: php

We have a large codebase, and every so often a var_dump used for testing and not removed/commented suddenly appears out of nowhere. There is a messy solution using XDebug (http://devzone.zend.com/1135/tracing-php-applications-with-xdebug/), but maybe there's something ingenous that can be done in PHP at runtime.

Also, I don't want to modify or search code via regex. I've tried using my own var_dump_v2, but it falls out of use quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible to use the disable_functions operation in php.ini to disable var_dump on your production server? I am not sure what the outcome of  this setting is (ie does it fail with an error, or silently) the documentation is not so clear.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php - see "disable_functions"

Also there is override_function:

```
<?php
override_function('var_dump', '$a', 'return 0;');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, can hardly believe that it exists

Answer (score 0):

There are actually ways to do this, if you have PECL available and [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) installed. You kan make runkit able to overide PHPs internal functions if you in php.ini set `runkit.internal_override` to "1".

For removing the var_dump function, you could use:

```
runkit_function_remove('var_dump');
```

In your case, not to get an error, you should probably instead use something like this:

```
runkit_function_redefine('var_dump', '','');
```

Take a look at the [runkit extensions documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php).

You may also want to take a look at "[Advanced PHP debugger](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php)", another extension that seems to offer an [override_function()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use monkey patching.

Just defines a namespace on the first line of your file and defines the function var_dump

```
     <?php
     namespace monkey;
     function var_dump($obj) {}
```

Of course, it implies that you do not use a namespace in your current file

You could use the function var_dump() prefixing it with the root namespace(): `\var_dump()`

Of course, all others native function will continue to work as usual as long as you do not override them in your namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `serialize()` or `json_encode()` if you have a large database? That will be very useful.

But take note, `serialize()` will give you a 1-line output somewhat like this:

```
's:0:"";s:5:"value";'
```

So you need to learn the anatomy of `serialize()` to use it: [PHP Serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147)

Comment: And, `serialize()` and `json_encode()` are way faster when used within large database: [Benchmarking Cache Transcoders in PHP](http://nitschinger.at/Benchmarking-Cache-Transcoders-in-PHP)

Comment: I think you meant to post this on a different question